# perl script lacking path for compiler - what compiler?

Tags: perl, path-variables, opendds

When following the openDDS [install guide](http://opendds.org/quickstart/GettingStartedWindows.html) I attempt to run `configure` from within the command prompt but receive this output:

C:\Users\Supervisor\Desktop\opendds>C:\Users\Supervisor\Desktop\opendds\configure.cmd

```
Can't find a compiler, set PATH or run this script with the --compiler option.
For Microsoft Visual C++, run this script from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.
Stopped at configure line 336.
```

This error relates to this section of code within the perl script (as seen by the line number):

```
if ($opts{'compiler'}) {
    my $standard = 0;
    for my $stdcomp (@{$platforminfo{$opts{'host'}}->{'compilers'}}) {
        $standard = 1 if $opts{'compiler'} eq $stdcomp;
    }
    $opts{'nonstdcompiler'} = 1 unless $standard;
}
else {
    print "Auto-detecting compiler\n" if $opts{'verbose'};
    for my $stdcomp (@{$platforminfo{$opts{'host'}}->{'compilers'}}) {
        my $path = which($stdcomp);
        if ($path) {
            print "Found $stdcomp at: $path\n" if $opts{'verbose'};
            $opts{'compiler'} = $stdcomp;
            last;
        }
    }
    if (!defined $opts{'compiler'}) {
        die "Can't find a compiler, set PATH or run this script with the ".
        "--compiler option.\n" . ($slash eq '\\' ? "  For Microsoft Visual C++, ".
        "run this script from the Visual Studio ".
        "Command Prompt.\n" : '') . "Stopped";
    }
}
```

What compiler does it want? I have `gcc` and `make` working - they are on the system path.

Comment: just add `--compiler=gcc`, should work

Comment: Bingo, thank you. Feel free to post as an answer and I will accept, if not I will answer myself to close the question in ~1 day.

Comment: First instruction: "Ensure that your environment has:
Visual Studio,
Perl"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that windows does not list `gcc` as a naturally installed compiler.

On linux it would have worked right away.

So just add `--compiler=gcc` if `gcc` is in the path, it should work.